# Regex - Replace the first comma and last comma from the csv list but leave the middle one

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex... but here goes.

So, Let's say I have this data.

```
13579,24680,13579,24680
13579,24680,13579,24680
13579,24680,13579,24680
13579,24680,13579,24680
```

So what I want is for it to replace the first comma, and the last comma with nothing. So I just end up with:

```
 1357924680,1357924680
 1357924680,1357924680
 1357924680,1357924680
 1357924680,1357924680
```

After it goes through.

I was thinking of a pattern somewhere along `^([^,]+),`

But as you can tell, this doesn't work. Any suggestions or should I rethink what I use to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
regex: ^([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)$
options: multiline
replace $1$2,$3$4
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in perl:

```
$match =~ s/^(.*?),(.*),(.*?)$/$1$2$3/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)
```

replace with

```
$1$2,$3$4
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ur0v)

Dependent on the way you access your text, you need to use the multiline modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby example

```
"13579,24680,13579,24680".gsub(/(.*?),(.*),(.*?)/,'\1\2\3')
=> "1357924680,1357924680"
```

and another example without using regex because it's always worth a try

```
"%s%s,%s%s" % "13579,24680,13579,24680".split(',')
=> "1357924680,1357924680"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  echo "13579,24680,13579,24680
"|sed -r 's#(^[0-9]+),(.*?),([0-9]+)$#\1\2\3#'
1357924680,1357924680
```